# How to add Dynamic column in sql server which is select column name from declare Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @Columnnew varchar(50)

set @Columnnew ='NewColumn12'

select
```

alter table dbo.Customers add @Columnnew

I have required like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EXEC to execute this dynamic sql, for example:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)    
DECLARE @Columnnew varchar(50)

SET @Columnnew ='NewColumn12'

SET @sqlCommand = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers ADD ' + @Columnnew + ' varchar(MAX)'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

For more info, see [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-2)

Comment: Thanks . But Error occure.      The definition for column 'NewColumn12' must include a data type.

Comment: Hi, yes you will need to supply the data type, I have put in the data type in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql looks like:

```
declare @Columnnew varchar(50)
declare @SQL varchar(300)

set @Columnnew ='NewColumn12'
set @SQL = 'alter table dbo.Customers add ' || @Columnnew ||'
execute sql
```

Comment: It is tagged as SQL Server, not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by red query as below:

```
declare @Columnnew varchar(50),@Query nvarchar(max)=''
set @Columnnew ='NewColumn12'
set @Query ='alter table dbo.Customers add ' +@Columnnew
exec (@Query )
```